# IEventBroker subscription handles the same event more than once and handles incorrectly

Tags: eclipse, event-handling, e4

I am bootstrapping the `IEventBroker` in a compat-layer Eclipse RCP app.

I have two views: `Triggerer` and `Receiver`.

`Triggerer` (excerpts):

```java
private IEventBroker eventBroker = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IEventBroker.class);

btn.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        IStructuredSelection selection = viewer.getStructuredSelection();
        List selectionList = selection.toList();
        for (Object s : selectionList) {
            if (s instanceof MyObject) {
                matches.add(s);
            }
        }
        eventBroker.send(MyEventConstants.TOPIC_OBJECT_CHANGED, matches);
    }
}
```

`Receiver` (excerpts):

```java
@Override
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    Object data = event.getProperty(EVENT_DATA);
    switch (event.getTopic()) {
    case MyEventConstants.TOPIC_OBJECT_CHANGED:
        try {
            if (data instanceof ArrayList) {
                List<MyObject> matches = null;
                try {
                    matches = (List<MyObject>) data;
                }
                catch (ClassCastException e) {
                }
                Subthing sub = buildSubthing(matches);
                getContentViewer().getContents()
                        .setAll(Collections.singletonList(sub));
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

`buildSubthing` does stuff with the respective received data, and sets it to the contents of a GEF4 editor.

In some cases this works just fine, in some it doesn't.

`handleEvent()` is triggered more than once, although the `event` hashCode is always the same, and I don't understand why. The topic is the same and the data is also the same. However, `buildSubthing` just stalls for no apprent reason with some data while it doesn't for other. The data is structurally the same in both cases.

How can I control how often `handleEvent` is called, as I think the number of times it's called is the reason while the `Subthing` is sometimes not correctly constructed?

Comment: How is `handleEvent` connected to the event broker? You might be better using `post` rather than `send` as you are current handling the event synchronously.

Comment: Connected also via `PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IEventBroker.class);`. Tried `post` before `send`, that didn't make any difference :(.

Comment: I don't see any reason for multiple calls in the code you have shown. We would have to see a proper [mcve] to make any progress - something we can actually test.

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. I think it might have been an issue with asynchronous logging after all, and not the `IEventBroker`. I debugged thoroughly and found that the event is *handled* only once, but logged more than once. More debugging to do, but not related to this question. Will not delete it so that you keep the upvotes.